# Phone's on screen navigation bar hides content

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I'm working on a website where I implement 100vh landing screen, but bottom navigation bar (phone's navigation with home, back options) hides the bottom of my content. I'm already using JavaScript window.innerHeight to make browser take into account space taken by address bar, but this doesn't seem to take into consideration phone's on screen UI. I'll be grateful for any ideas on how to solve this issue.

JS

```
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```

CSS

```
 height: 100vh;
 height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
```

As a part of design I'm implementing an animated arrow linking to the beginning of page's content.

You can check it out on http://jakubsramek.com/cs/

Comment: you added the metadata ?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Yes, I do. As mentioned above, the issue isn't viewport width, but viewport height.

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to use
`height: 100%;`
instead of
`height: 100vh;`

Remember, if you're having difficulty getting the height to actually fill the screen, you will need to style all parent nodes (up to the root of the document) `height: 100%`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use since window.innerHeight change when you click or scroll

```
<body onresize="resizemyDiv()">
```

or

```
window.onresize = function (){
 // some code here to get window size
 // and adjust the size or your div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this just with CSS. You can use the `calc` function is CSS, you subtract the height of the navigation bar (let's say it's 30px) from the 100vh.
Example:

```
 .element {
   height: calc(100vh - 30px);
 }
```

Comment: size of the adress bar isn't always 30px, and it is not shown when you scroll down

Comment: @phoenixstudio you can either edit the design to your own creative way. An example is putting some borders on the top & bottom so there isn't any important content there. If editing the design isn't an option, you can always go for an onScroll behavior event. Determine what the conditions of the navigation bar showing (maybe scrolling down? Sorry I'm not an android user), and then match these conditions in your own onScroll event to either show or hide whatever content you're planning to put there.

Comment: thank you for explanation, I just wanted to point that there is no need to guess (guess the size or if scrolling or not), just use innerHeight and update style onresize event

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Ok guys just figured it out, the issue was with my javascript file handling the vh was set to async. Thanks for help!